# Synchronous in-app billing service setup

Tags: android, android-billing

I'm using a google provided code (**IabHelper.java**, etc.) to setup in-App billing in my Android App. The provided code is asynchronous in the sense that I need to specify a callback function that will fun upon successfully binding a service.

However, I found myself in a need to possess information about current subscriptions across different activities. So I decided to **bind the billing service synchronously** in onCreate method of the Activity and keep it in a static variable. This should be relatively fast since Google Play Services do some caching. The code I use is the following:

```
        // this - current activity
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        mService = new BillingService(this, latch);
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
```

And then in `onIabSetupFinished` I call `latch.countDown()`. Unfortunately, `countDown` is never get executed and my code is stuck in `await()`. Does anyone know how to solve this or suggest an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onIabSetupFinished()` is called from `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` which is scheduled for execution on the main thread of your app. It can't run though since you are blocking your main thread with `latch.await()`.

You could not block the app and instead just display an uncancellable `ProgressDialog` until you get the information from the IAB service.

Comment: To continue, you I should close the dialog from ``onIabSetupFinished()``? So there is no other way?

Comment: Exactly, close the dialog in `onIabSetupFinished()`. The main thread is not used just for UI but for service connection callbacks and other things as well. So it is not a good idea to block it.